# What is the value of $a$ & $r$ when 2 points on the graph are given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am working on algebraic functions and I am stuck on this problem:

$f(x) = a * r^x$
$(2,1),(3,1.5)$

This would be a simple problem if it weren't for that $1.5$ -

So, I have plugged in $2$ and $1$ into the function and this is what I got:
[image: My Problem Solving]

[I also solved for $3,1.5$]
So, this is where I get stuck every time.

I have tried solving it multiple ways but it always ends up to the same effect, where $r$ is always $=$ to something funny that is unsolvable - at least for me.

Could someone explain how you got your answer so that I can understand the process? I know how to do this type of problem, but it is just *this* one that I can't get!!!!

Thanks for your help and time!

***EDIT***: I need this simplified, that is why I cant leave $r^2 = 1.5$

Comment: Just for community advice: Drawings are typically taboo in Math SE _mainly_ because there are mobile users that use Math SE and they won't be able to _see_ any pictures that you post in your question. While I'm not saying that you should get rid of your picture, I would just like for you to be mindful of this.

Comment: @KingDuken - thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we have the function f(x)=ar^x, then by substituting the first point given, namely $(2,1)$, we'll get:

$$1=ar^2$$

Similarly, substituting $(3, \frac{3}{2})$, we end up with

$$\frac{3}{2}=ar^3$$

Now, to find $a\neq 0$ and $r\neq 0 $, you should divide this two equations, what you get then?

Comment: $r = 3/2$ $\Rightarrow$ we can find the $a$!!!

Comment: But why couldn't I find the square root of 1 and get $ar = 1$? Or is that not the proper way to do it?

Comment: I think that the idea of your approach was correct, but something went wrong implementing that, i.e: you want to write $a=\frac{1}{r^2}$, and the substitute it to the second equation, right? So, $\frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot r^3$, thus $\frac{3}{2}=r$.

Comment: So the way I solved for $r$ in $ar^2 = 1$ was incorrect, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(2)=ar^2=1$$
$$a=\frac{1}{r^2}$$
$$f(3)=ar^{3}=1.5$$
$$r=1.5$$
$$a=\frac{1}{(1.5)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, though I don't understand one part of you solution.

How did you get $r = 1.5$ from $ar^3 = 1.5$?

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen Because $a=\frac{1}{r^2}$. On substituting, you get $r=1.5$.